# Hyperlink within a OpenOffice calc using c#

Tags: c#, hyperlink, openoffice.org

I've made a spreadsheet in openoffice using c# with several different sheets. On sheet 1 is a list of all the names of the rest of the sheet. how is it possible to set up a hyperlink from each of these cells to there corresponding sheet.

I have looked through the internet but i have struggled to find any helpful information. Can anybody point me in the right direction on how to program this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if i understand you right, but this may be helpful, put it in your cell:

```
=HYPERLINK("MyTableName.C3")
```

This (should) jump to cell C3 in table MyTableName.
To just jump to a table use

```
=HYPERLINK("#MyTableName")
```

I cannot try it because i don't use OpenOffice

Source: http://www.ooowiki.de/HyperLink

Comment: sorry i have explained my problem very clearly. i have made this spreadsheet using c# and im asking how to create a hyperlink using c#

Comment: put the =HYPERLINK() formula in a cell

Comment: i'm taking data out of plm files and putting them into a blank spreadsheet file therefore im typing nothing directly into the spreadsheet file, it is all being done in visual studios using c#

Comment: then use something like `myCell = string.Format("=HYPERLINK(\"#{0}\")", TableName);`

Comment: i get the error message of "cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'unoidl.com.sun.star.table.XCell"

Comment: i'm not familier with this interface, but try `myCell.setFormula("=HYPERLINK.........");`

Comment: i managed to get  myCell.setFormula("=HYPERLINK(" + findSheet + ";" + nameSheet + ")"); to work where findsheet is sheet name and name sheet is name of the hyperlink. thanks for all your help!